# css Syntax Error while building dojo

Tags: css, build, dojo

I am using dojo 1.9.3. I am facing issues in css file while building dojo using build.bat. Here is my css file code :

```
@import url("TimeDriverCommon.css");
@import url("DialogCommon.css");

@import url( "timedriver/Dialog.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/Help.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/Blocker.css" );

@import url( "timedriver/dialogs/SendMessage.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/layout/BorderContainer.css" );

@import url( "timedriver/form/RadioButton.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/PasswordStrength.css" );

@import url( "timedriver/invitee/wizard.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/AddToCalendar.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/ApptDetails.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/Error.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/ProvideInformation.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/SelectDate.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/booking/BookingStep.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/booking/Confirmation.css" );
@import url( "timedriver/invitee/booking/Welcome.css" );

/***** MAIN CONTENT *****/
#headerArea {
    height: 72px; /* to accommodate logo */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white/*#BAD0E2*/;
    max-width: 1012px;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center */
    position: relative; /* need offset origin for headerNonLogoAreas (e.g. gradient) */
    font-size: 85%;
}

.psNoHeader #headerArea {
    display: none;
}

html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {  
    background-image: url('/td/_images/mainGradient.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 -220px;
    background-color: #8A90A0;
}

.dj_ie6 #headerArea {
    width: expression((document.body.offsetWidth > 1012 ? 1012 : document.body.offsetWidth) + "px");
}

#bodyArea {
    position: absolute;
    top: 72px; /* same as headerArea height */
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 85%;
}

.psNoHeader #bodyArea {
    top: 0;
}

/* IE 6 & 7 work-around for box offset positioning */
.dj_ie6 #bodyArea,
.dj_ie7 #bodyArea {
    bottom: ;
    height: expression(document.body.offsetHeight - 72 + "px"); /* 72 = height of header */
}

#scrollingArea {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center */
    max-width: 1012px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; /* IE 6 needs this to keep the scroll bas above the position:absolute content! */
}

/* IE 6 workaround for lack of max-width support */
.dj_ie6 #scrollingArea {
    width: expression((document.body.offsetWidth > 1012 ? 1012 : document.body.offsetWidth) + "px");
    overflow: auto;
}

.leftpanel {
    left: 25px;
    width: 666px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.rightpanel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.75em; /* this must match the combined top of .leftpanel and height of .wizardheader */
    right: 25px;
    width: 272px;
}

.rightpanel .brandingLinks {
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    color:gray;
}

.rightpanel #sendMessageLink {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.brandingContainer {
    text-align: center;
}

.brandingLinks {
    text-align: left;
}

.logoContainer #logoContainerImg {
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.headerNonLogoArea {
    bottom:4px;
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:190px;
    position:absolute;
    right:5px;
}

#headerGradient {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.headerActionArea {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.headerIdentificationArea {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 5px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    /*color: #ffffff;*/
}

.ttLogo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 6px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 177px;
}

/***** END MAIN CONTENT *****/

/***** COMMON STYLES *****/

.copyright {
    /* we're not currently showing copyrights on the booking side */
    display: none;
}

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/***** START 'Send Message Dialog (Wizard)' *****/
#dialogSendMessage {
    width: 575px;
}

#dialogSendMessage .header {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: #E7EBF3;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CBD6DB;
    color: #585757;
}

#dialogSendMessage .content {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 90%;
}

#dialogSendMessage .footer {
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 35px;
    background-color: #E7EBF3;
    border-top: 2px solid #CBD6DB;
}

/***** STOP 'Send Message Dialog (Wizard)' *****/

/*
 * This is really effed up, but dojo uses blockquote tags to format indents in the Editor.
 * Therefore, we need to style them similarly in our app.
 */
.timedriver blockquote {
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1em 0 1em 40px; /* it seems that this really should be pixels, not 2.5em as I would expect (legacy from Netscape/IE) */
}


.timedriver .videoContainer {
    position: relative;
    height: 120px;
    -moz-border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border:6px solid #F3F3F5;
}

.timedriver .videoListLeftBar {
    border-left:1px solid #E8AB1D;
    border-top:1px solid #E8AB1D;
    bottom:9px;
    left:11px;
    position:absolute;
    top:23px;
    width:15px;
}
.timedriver .videoContainerConfirmation {
    height: 220px;
}

.timedriver .videoContainerConfirmation .videoListLeftBar{
    top: 60px;
}

.timedriver .learnMore {
    color:blue;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:15px 37px;
}

.timedriver .learnMore img{
    display:block;
    margin:10px 40px;
    border: none;
}

.timedriver .videoListRight {
    position:absolute;
    left:25px;
    top:9px;
}

.timedriver .videoContainerConfirmation .videoListRight {
    top: 29px;
}

.timedriver .videoListRight .videoArrow {
    height:29px;
    width:29px;
    display: block;
}

.timedriver .videoListRight p {
    color:blue;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin:-25px 0 0 37px;
    vertical-align:top;
    width:180px;
}

.timedriver .videoLinks {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    left: 30px;
}

.timedriver .videoLinks img {
    height:13px;
    margin-right:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:11px;
}

.timedriver #videoConfirmationBlock {
    margin-top: 18px;
}

.timedriver #videoConfirmationBlock .videoContainerConfHeader {
    color: red; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -50px;
}

.psNoHeader .bottonPanel {
    display: none;
}

.bottonPanel {
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    font-style:italic;
    position: relative; 
    top: 14px;  
    right: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;
    clear: both;
}

.dj_ie7 .bottonPanel, .dj_ie6 .bottonPanel {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}

.bottonPanel a{
    color:#557EAD;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:10px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.psNoHeader .poweredBy {
    display: block!important;
    color:black;
    font-size:10px;
    font-style:italic;
    position: absolute;
}

.dj_ie7 .psNoHeader .poweredBy {
    bottom: -10px;
}

.psNoHeader .errorcontainer .poweredBy {
    bottom: -10px;
}

.dj_ie7 .psNoHeader .errorcontainer .poweredBy {
    bottom: 0;
}

.psNoHeader .poweredBy a {
    color:#557EAD;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:10px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

It gives me the following error :

`[exec] error(307) Failed to evaluate module tagged as pure AMD (fell back to processing with regular expressions). module: timetrade/themes/TimeDriverBooking.css; error: SyntaxError: missing name after .@`

What is the reason for this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css Syntax Error while building dojo 1.9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800260/css-syntax-error-while-building-dojo-1-9-3)

Comment: This is the *exact same question* as the other one you posted. **Do not double-post** on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your timetrade/package.json and timetrade/timetrade.profile.js appropriately to mark your CSS files as copyOnly - and not AMD.

A good example can be found in the dojo source tree - see dijit/package.json, dijit/dijit.profile.js.  Note how package.json points to the dijit.profile.js file to give the dojo build system instructions on how to build the package.

Also see the build system documentation - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/buildSystem.html#build-buildsystem